# Jquery data Table plugin with asp.net repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, repeater

I am using jQuery datatable plugin for paging and seraching. And I am applying this on repeater, it is working fine on client side.

How can I change it server side so that I can pass parameter value from drop down to stored procedure to fetch only required data rows?

In short I mean custom paging. Now I am binding all data rows from table to repeater on page load. How can I pass parameter to it?

Here is a look at the aspx page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#TblDataTable').dataTable({

            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bSort": true,
            //    "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Productindex.aspx/LoadProductList()",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": "{'sEcho': '" + aoData[0].value + "'}",
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
            },
            // "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "sLengthMenu": "Page Size",

            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200], [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200]],
            "aoColumns": [
                   { "bSearchable": true },
                   { "bSearchable": false },
                   { "bSearchable": false },
                   { "bSearchable": false },
                   { "bSearchable": false },
                   { "bSearchable": true },
                   { "bSearchable": false },

            ],

        });
    });<script>
```

And below is what I am doing in C# on page load I am calling this method

```
  public void LoadProductList()
  {
        Products objProducts;

        List<Products> objProductlist;

        try
        {
            objProducts = new Products();
            objProductlist = objProducts.GetProductList();
            rptProduct.DataSource = objProductlist;
            rptProduct.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

What I want is to pass some parameter to the `GetProductList` method to fetch relevant data only. I mean if I select 5 from dropdown, then I'll fetch 5 rows

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this kind of plugin, but I could say that the point is on the method

```
$.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": 'json',
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": "{'sEcho': '" + aoData[0].value + "'}",
                "success": fnCallback
});
```

I don't know if you have ever used this, but you should at first mark the method LoadProductList as static method and use the attribute [WebMethod]. Then add the argument in the signautre of this method like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static [List<Produit>] LoadProductList(int rows)
```

Produit should be described as Serializable by using [Serializable] attribute.
Then, the server side will be ok, but I advise to test it with console program or soupUI
Right now, we could return to the client side. Look at this line in the method $.ajax

```
"data": "{'sEcho': '" + aoData[0].value + "'}",
```

you should replace 'sEcho' by rows and aoData[0].value by the number of rows that you would like to return.
Then in the method fnCallback, I think you should pass a function object with its signature like method(result) and in this method, you could use result.d to get the results passed by the method LoadProductList on your server side. For test, you could try to use console.log([object of javascript]) to log result and result.d if d is used by jQuery.

By the way, I found this line in your script

```
"sAjaxSource": "/Productindex.aspx/LoadProductList()",
```

I think you shoud make sure that the path is correct, if not, you should use ../ to jump to parent and '()' is not necessary(if this property is like sSource which you have used in $.ajax, and you should pass the correct method path to the argument sSource which could be something like '%parent%/Productindex.aspx/LoadProductList').

I hope this brief desciption could respond your question.